# What happens if neither player decides to do anything?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My question is about Magic The Gathering. What happens if both players perpetually decide to do nothing in a turn, except draw and then discard to 7. What happens then?

Comment: How about both players play Platinum Angels and then can't destroy them? That makes this a question

Comment: Eventually they get bored and go play Mario Kart instead?

Answer (score 10):

The most likely outcome is that one player loses when he has no more cards to draw:

> 104.3c If a player is required to draw more cards than are left in his or her library, he or she draws the remaining cards, and then loses the game the next time a player would receive priority.

Other possible outcome is a draw during a tournament game with time limit, though a player will likely run out of cards before they reach the limit.